# How to install packages from Ubuntu installation media offline?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Ubuntu 18.04 installation media contains `dkms` and its dependencies in `pool` directory. But `apt` doesn't recognize USB flash as a package source.

How can I tell `apt` to pull packages with dependencies from an installation media connected to a USB port without copying files to `cache` or manually installing them using `dpkg`?

Comment: Doesn't `apt-cdrom` work for USB drives? `apt-cdrom -d /mount-point add`?

Comment: @muru I can't check it now. I will be able to do it only in a few days. If someone checks, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Offline install of dkms. Not network, install media on USB Stick**
With Bionic Desktop install media, usb stick on `/dev/sdb1`

1. Backup `/etc/apt/sources.list` Mount USB key and create new `/etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Install dkms
3. Revert changes on `/etc/apt/sources.list`

---

Backup sources.list and prepare new source

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.BCK
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list
if [ ! -d /media/apt ]; then sudo mkdir /media/apt; fi
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/apt
sudo apt-cdrom add --cdrom=/media/apt
sudo apt-get update
```

Install

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Revert changes on `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb2
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.BCK /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Does installing `dkms` from the USB work?

Comment: I would suggest to improve this answer with a more clear manual for a newbie. And als add a command to remove this source, because it will throw errors when the stick is not inserted.

Comment: @muru : works on a clean install

Comment: @cmak.fr Did it install without a network connection?

Comment: @Pilot6 ... not sure

Comment: Then it is not a test at all. It could install the packages from the net, not from the USB.

Comment: i know, plz wait

Comment: done... insteed of playing with priority, i created a temp new sources.list

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to resolve the same issue after installing Ubuntu 18.04 desktop version from a live USB drive, but the other answer didn't quite work because my USB drive was automatically mounted after boot, and the `apt` command was expecting the USB drive to be at `/media/cdrom`.

After booting the newly installed Ubuntu, the USB drive was automatically mounted at `/media/username/UBUNTU 18_0`, where *username* will be your user name.

To use that as a source in `apt` I did the following:

```
sudo apt-cdrom --no-auto-detect --cdrom=/media/username/UBUNTU\ 18_0 -m add
sudo rmdir -f /media/cdrom
sudo ln -snf /media/username/UBUNTU\ 18_0 /media/cdrom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install package_name
```

The `ln` was necessary because `apt` was expecting the source to be in `/media/cdrom` in my case.

The `apt-cdrom` options are different from other answers. `-m` prevents it from being unmounted.

You can still do the backup and restore of the `sources.list` as written in the other answers.